# cypress:Allow reading non-existent files in cy.readFile

Tags: cypress

I have dropdown with many items which is coming from an other module first column.
so,Those column value is created dynamically.I am trying to write those column values in JSON file so that i can click on the dropdown item without hardcoding.Before writing I am reading file using readfile() but that file does not exist for the first time so how to check if cypress/fixtures/xxx.json file exist before writing into it.Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue and I see that `cy.readfile()` fails if file doesn't exist so cypress docs suggests using `cy.task()` to read a file that may not exist and I think we can use `cy.task()` so that if the file doesn't exist we create an empty file, this is the idea and I'll try implementing it and share code.

[Reference](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile#Existence)